# There is no intellisense in vs code node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, visual-studio-code

There is no intellisence in visual studio code. i have installed and tried many extensions but it does not helping me out. It only shows those functions and variables that are already used in my code file. Here is the list on extension i have installed and the screenshot.[image: screenshot of vs code intellisence and extension that i have installed]

Comment: VS code only gives intellisense when the function or class you are using has proper documentation. Like `express` npm.

Comment: I have used express before this but its same. Only those functions and variables are in intellisense after “.” that are already in the code file, then I decided to reinstall vs code and extensions and start new project.

Comment: VS Code fetches type-definitons for node and you should be getting intellisense there without any of those extensions. Check your VS Code settings under JavaScript and see if anything is disabled that is related to Suggestions and Intellisense.

Comment: Also, node should be in your path for JavaScript Language Service to get those definitions. Further reading: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript

Comment: There is no problem with the vs code i just solve this by npm install  —save @types/node

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no problem with the vs code i just solve this by

```
npm install --save @types/node
```

This is one of development dependencies and `—save` is just an argument that reflect the info related to this in your `package.json` file

Comment: interesting.  is this because it is typescript ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this command in Mac :

```
sudo npm install -g --save @types/node --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```