# How do I enable Node.js intellisense in VSCode WITHOUT making a node_modules folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Yes, I've seen a dozen questions on this exact subject, I'll list a few dozen below:

[How to enable Node.js code autocompletion in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777494/how-to-enable-node-js-code-autocompletion-in-vscode)
[There is no intellisense in vs code node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989823/there-is-no-intellisense-in-vs-code-node-js)
[Visual Studio Code Intellisense not working for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235242/visual-studio-code-intellisense-not-working-for-javascript)

All of these questions have the same answer: install `@types/node`, which makes a package.json and a node_modules folder.

I want to work on a simple script, one that will be one file, starts with a node shebang, and has no package dependencies. I'm working in a dropbox folder. I don't *want* to create a hundred-thousand subfolders under node_modules that my dropbox has to sync because no one knows how to write a package without a dozen redundant dependencies anymore. I'd be perfectly fine with installing the types package globally, but I have yet to see that function without an absolute path to the node installation (dropbox folder, remember?).

**Is there a way to enable autocompletion in VSCode without needing to install packages as a sibling in the folder structure?**

Answer (score 1):

Apparently creating a `jsconfig.json` file as follows in the same folder will allow one to enable node.js autocompletion without needing to install anything. (Though I did do this after globally installing `@types/node`, so that might be required.)

```json
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "node"
        ]
    }
}
```

This will apparently tell VSCode to automatically search for and include the given types? Either way, it enables node.js autocompletion.

Comment: works like a charm. I didn't have to install any package