# Node.js socket.io suggestions not showing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, socket.io

i was following a youtube tutorial, and i was stuck on one thing which i was unable to find on internet, the thing is my vscode is not  showing suggestions for socket.io
[pic of my vscode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I5Yf.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can you link the youtube video? Secondly, I assume the person in the video was probably using [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), which enforces typings on variables giving you Intellisense (suggestions).

Comment: https://youtu.be/rxzOqP9YwmM

Comment: Maybe try your luck with these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65183135/11650207, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36235539/11650207, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54991685/11650207